# Regex to get value from JSON field

Tags: regex, curl

Considering the json below I need to get the value `text` from `grand_total`. The most close regular expression that I achieved was:

```regex
"grand_total":(.*?)\}
```

```
{
    "data": [{
        "grand_total": {
            "digital": "4:41",
            "hours": 4,
            "minutes": 41,
            "text": "4 hrs 41 mins",
            "total_seconds": 16880.662732
        }
    }],
    "end": "2019-09-04T02:59:59Z",
    "start": "2019-09-03T03:00:00Z"
}
```

Comment: why don't you use a JSON parser?

Comment: if you do really want a regex for this: `"text": "(.+?)(?=")` will work as long as there are no other attributes called text.

Comment: I can't use third party libs to parse json. I simplified the json and there're other `text` attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On `s` mode, an expression similar to the following might extract the desired value,

```
"grand_total":\s*{.*?"text"\s*:\s*"([^"]*)"
```

and you can likely call that using `$1`.

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/OYu5kH/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/OYu5kH/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---